# Tomcat - логгирование

Tags: java, tomcat

Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно осуществить вывод своих сообщений - LOGGER.log(Level.xxx "msg");
в файл, который будет расположен в ${catalina.base}/logs.

Можно каким-то образом подкрутить logging.properties непосредственно Tomcat. Дабы он сообщения, которые я добавляю в сервлет выводил в отдельный файл

пример кода

```
    Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TestServlet.class.getName());

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.print("<h1>Hello Servlet</h1>");
    LOGGER.info("HELLO");
}
```

я добавил в properties

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=log.%u.%g.txt
java.util.logging.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
java.util.logging.FileHandler.prefix = myLogs.
java.util.logging.FileHandler.encoding=UTF-8
java.util.logging.FileHandler.append=true
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=1000000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=5
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

но не могу понять как их использовать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD - дополнил**
 Собственно решил не мудрить и тупо запилил свой логгер, который пишет в catalina.base

```
    private static Logger LOGGER;
private static boolean init = false;

public static Logger getLogger(String loggerName) {
    LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(loggerName);
    if (!init) {
        try {
            Handler fileHandler = new FileHandler(System.getProperty("catalina.base") + "\\log.%u.%g.txt",
                    1000000,
                    5,
                    true);
            fileHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
            fileHandler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
            LOGGER.addHandler(fileHandler);
            LOGGER.setLevel(Level.ALL);
            init = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            init = false;
        }
    }
    return LOGGER;
}
```